# android : make imageview full screen size

Tags: android

I know this has been asked in stackoverflow few times ; I tried all the answers in vain. I have a custom imageview (for scroll/zoom) in my android app. I programmatically set the image to be displayed in the imageview (so, the imageview is empty in the IDE). However I try, there seems to be some padding to the left & top of the imageview which am unable to remove. Please help. This is the code (the following is one of the possible options I tried from stackoverflow)
It's not possible to change the scaletype from matrix as my code for touch/zoom depends on the matrix scale type.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ActivityHome" >

<myTouchImageView
android:id="@+id/imgView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:scaleType="matrix" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, this is what I get :

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1- Change `android:scaleType="matrix"` to `android:scaleType="fitXY"` which means that the image will be stretched to fit all the sides of the parent ( ImageView ) , but this will change its resolution, if you want to keep the resolution use `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

Comment: that's not possible @3amoura as my code for touch/zoom depends on the matrix scale type.

Comment: 1- Would you please add you java code where you set the image of the imageView
2- Remove the Orientation in the RelativeLayout.
3- Is this screen shot from the eclipse IDE or from the phone because from eclipse it not accurate specially when ScaleType is used